# Is the Stellar Consensus Protocol paper peer reviewed?

Tags: consensus

Is the stellar consensus protocol peer reviewed?

If yes, could you share some resources pointing to the peer review?

If not, what would need to happen to have a peer review of this part of the stellar whitepaper?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean peer reviewed?

Answer (score 1):

A peer reviewed [academic paper](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/~dm/home/papers/lokhava:stellar-core.pdf) on the Stellar system was published at SOSP in 2019.  It includes a section on SCP and another section on the formal verification of SCP.

Answer (score 0):

The academic paper cited in [this answer](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/a/2742/683) references the publicly available whitepaper, which in turn seems not to have been peer reviewed.

You can also see this by the fact that the Theorem 3 has a quite obvious flaw in it's proof.